# Make h4 tag line break at beginning of new line

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a for each loop that puts input fields between h4 tags, but when I open the web page on my phone I saw that the text had a line break that looked kind of strange. [image: Strange text]

I want the text to display as 'The [text input] scenes were cut from the film.' in a way that is easy to read. To do this the text input field needs to remain the height of one row of text and wherever the line break happens, it should start underneath 'The'. I've searched for a lot of solutions and until now I haven't found any solution.

Is this something that can be fixed with just some easy CSS or does it also require me to do some JS?

```
<form action="" method="post" id="answers" class="card-title">
<h4>The </h4>
<input class="form-control answer_input" autocomplete="off" id="answer_1" style="min-width:40px; width: 100px; max-width300pheight:30px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" autofocus="" type="text">
<h4> scenes were cut from the film. (horrify)</h4>
```

This is the current code for the screenshot you see above. It has some CSS added that makes it a flex row.

This is the blade code to show the form

```
<?php  $i=0; $answers = explode('|', $question->correct_answer); ?>
          <form action="" method="post" id="answers" class="card-title">
                  <?php $sections = explode('___', $question->question);  $c = 0; $answers_processed = 0; ?>
                  @foreach($sections as $section)
                          <h4>{{$section}}</h4>
                          <?php $c = $c + 1; $i = $i +1;?>
                          @if($i < 3 && $answers_processed !== count($answers))
                              <input class="form-control answer_input" autocomplete="off" id="answer_{{$i}}" style="min-width:40px; width: {{strlen($answers[$i - 1]) * 10}}px; max-width300pheight:30px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" type="text" autofocus>
                          @endif
                          <?php $answers_processed = $answers_processed + 1; ?>
                  @endforeach
          </form>
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Well why the heck are you making this _two_ headlines? This is _one_ headline, that just happens to have an input field somewhere in it.

Comment: @CBroe check the edit, I added some blade code that makes the form

Comment: So ... change it?

Comment: Could you give a code example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be *two* headlines, but rather one headline with an input field somewhere in it.

You choose the h4-input-h4 structure based on problems handling/outputting the data in a loop. But instead of *exploding* your data at the `___` delimiter, you could simply *replace* that delimiter with the HTML code for the input field (str_replace should do).

That way, you don't have to deal with two parts of one question any more, but can simply output the question "as one" inside a single h4 element. That makes more sense semantically - and will make your problem displaying it as intended go away, too ... At least for the most part; you might want to play with the padding of the input field and the line-height of the h4 a little to get the desired look & behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your first  balise :

```
<form action="" method="post" id="answers" class="card-title">
<h4>The 
<input class="form-control answer_input" autocomplete="off" id="answer_1" style="min-width:40px; width: 100px; max-width300pheight:30px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" autofocus="" type="text"></h4>
<h4> scenes were cut from the film. (horrify)</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't close the tag `h4` before input. `h4` has `display: block` which put a break when closing

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="answers" class="card-title">
<h4>The
<input class="form-control answer_input" autocomplete="off" id="answer_1" style="min-width:40px; width: 100px; max-width: 300px;height:30px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px" autofocus="" type="text">
scenes were cut from the film. (horrify)</h4>
```

Comment: Check the edit I did, if I would do that the foreach would break

Comment: How would it "break"? Sounds like you started off with a data structure that is messy already ... so that's likely also the point where you should start _fixing_ this. Why are two parts that clearly belong together ("The " and " scenes were cut from the film. (horrify)") stored as two "sections" on the same level?

Comment: Suggestion: Store your questions in a format like sprintf uses - with placeholders, that you can then replace (using aforementioned function) with either an input field or just a word (to show an already completed answer, or sth like that) - `'The %s scenes were cut from the film. (horrify)'`

Comment: that is a php problem. put starting tag `h4` before loop and closing tag after the loop.

Comment: Its already like that @CBroe. In the database the part where an input field is supposed to be is filled with ___

Comment: @stefanbachert I'll give it a try

Comment: Well then simply stop exploding them at that point, and instead replace `___` with the input field ...

Comment: @CBroe haven't  thought about that one yet. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ;)

```
<h4>
@foreach($sections as $section)
      <?php $c = $c + 1; $i = $i +1;?>
          {{$section}}
      @if($i < 3 && $answers_processed !== count($answers))
          <input class="form-control answer_input mb-2" autocomplete="off" id="answer_{{$i}}" style="min-width:40px; width: {{strlen($answers[$i - 1]) * 14}}px; max-width300x; display: inline-block; height:30px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" type="text" autofocus>
      @endif
      <?php $answers_processed = $answers_processed + 1; ?>
@endforeach
</h4>
```